# Disable client reqeust body buffering in nginx

Tags: file, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, buffering

```
  location /api/file-upload/ {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080/file-upload/;
  }
```

Below warning has been encountered with above nginx configuration. I want to disable client reqeust body buffering in nginx.

[warn] 30#30: *1 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001, client: 172.30.0.1, server: _, request: "POST /api/file-upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/webapp/file"

Comment: Have you tried setting `proxy_http_version 1.1;`?  The [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) states that HTTP 1.1 chunked uploads are always buffered unless you allow it to be passed onto the upstream.